# MySQL: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; autoincrement vs another key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, mysql-error-1075

Here is a table in MySQL 5.3.X+ db:

```
CREATE TABLE members` (
  `id` int(11)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `memberid` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
  `Time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL ,
  UNIQUE (memberid),
  PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

**Id** column is never used in queries, it is just for visual convenience (so it's easy to see how the table grows). **Memberid** is an actual key, is unique, and **memberid** is used in queries to identify any member (WHERE memberid='abcde').

My question is: how to keep auto_increment, but make memberid as a primary key? Is that possible?
When I try to create this table with **PRIMARY KEY (memberid)**, I get an error:

> 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

What is the best choice (Hopefully, there is a way to keep id column so performance is good and queries identify any user by memberid, not by id), if the performance is very important (although the disk space is not)?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You **can** have an auto-Incrementing column that is not the `PRIMARY KEY`, as long as there is an index (key) on it:

```
CREATE TABLE members ( 
  id int(11)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  memberid VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL , 
  `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
  firstname VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL , 
  lastname VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL , 
  PRIMARY KEY (memberid) ,
  KEY (id)                          --- or:    UNIQUE KEY (id)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Comment: This will make the ENGINE => MYISAM to INNODB

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I'm not sure I follow you. The table in the question was MyISAM.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I am using AWS Aurora, and faced `1075` issue when i was trying out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment. Then tried your suggestion of adding `KEY(id)` then got the warning as `1 warning(s): 1266 Using storage engine InnoDB for table 'MYTABLE'`, means i am not able to create that table with MYISAM engine though it is mentioned in DDL

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar See https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/ : ***Certain MySQL features like the MyISAM storage engine are not available with Amazon Aurora.*** Welcome to 2018, MyISAM is dead ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thank you! and yes; your solution has worked in my local mysql db.

Answer (score 18):

First create table without auto_increment,

```
CREATE TABLE `members`(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `memberid` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
    `Time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    `firstname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL ,
    `lastname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (memberid) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

after set id as index,

```
ALTER TABLE `members` ADD INDEX(`id`);
```

after set id as auto_increment,

```
ALTER TABLE `members` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

---

Or

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `memberid` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
    `Time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    `firstname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL ,
    `lastname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`memberid`),
      KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Thank you, setting an index first helped me in manually adding Auto_increment to a column in an existing table.

Comment: I got this Message: 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1681 Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1 0.094 sec for MySQL 8 InnoDB engine

Answer (score 4):

You can make the id the primary key, and set member_id to `NOT NULL UNIQUE`. (Which you've done.) Columns that are `NOT NULL UNIQUE` can be the target of foreign key references, just like a primary key can.  (I'm pretty sure that's true of all SQL platforms.)

At the conceptual level, there's no difference between `PRIMARY KEY` and `NOT NULL UNIQUE`. At the physical level, this is a MySQL issue; other SQL platforms will let you use a sequence without making it the primary key.

But if performance is really important, you should think twice about widening your table by  four bytes per row for that tiny visual convenience.  In addition, if you switch to INNODB in order to enforce foreign key constraints, MySQL will use your primary key in a clustered index. Since you're not using your primary key, I imagine that could hurt performance.

Answer (score 3):

I think i understand what the reason of your error.
First you click auto AUTO INCREMENT field then select it as a primary key.

> The Right way is First You have to select it as a primary key then you
>   have to click auto AUTO INCREMENT field.

Very easy.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the above issue, first of all if suppose tables contains more than 1 primary key then first remove all those primary keys and add first AUTO INCREMENT field as primary key then add another required primary keys which is removed earlier. Set AUTO INCREMENT option for required field from the option area.

Answer (score 1):

Identified this solution while reading this thread. Figured id post this for the next guy possibly.

When dealing with Laravel migration file from a package, I Ran into this issue.

My old value was

```
$table->increments('id');
```

My new

```
$table->integer('id')->autoIncrement();
```

Answer (score 0):

It only let you add auto_increment on a column with an index. **Make sure you haven't set auto_increment on other column**.

ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY COLUMN thecolumn desiredtype AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY