# Existing table add auto increment primary key - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing product table which is already populated with 120 records and I have tried below SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD product_id 
    INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

But it's given me the error:

> Error:  #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: you tried which query?

Comment: ALTER TABLE product ADD product_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

Comment: `ALTER TABLE product ADD column product_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: Show your table description. A table can have only one primary key and if you are defining auto_increment column it has to be primary key i.e you cannot have one column as auto_increment and other column as primary key

Comment: I refer you to a prior post that might assist answering the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114535/mysql-1075-incorrect-table-definition-autoincrement-vs-another-key

Comment: For SQL SERVER: `ALTER TABLE product ADD ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY`

Answer (score 1):

Here is work around

- create a simple column with autoincrement
- browse the table and again make this newly added column as primary key

You are done !

:) Thanks to Guy who is not in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Friend
If you try to do this in MSSQL then your script will be this.
suppose your table is below

```
create table product
(
 name varchar(20),
 product_type varchar(20)
)
```

and suppose you entered some record in this table after that you want to add a column that name product_id with auto increment and primary key. Then you use this script that is below

```
alter table product add product_ID int primary key identity(1,1)
```

suppose this will be help full for you.

Answer (score -1):

There can only be one auto increment field per table. But, you could have a calculated field based on the auto increment field. Or, you could have an int field where you manage the sequence by front end code or by a trigger. And also you could use a [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) in SQL Server.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySequence START WITH 100;

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    RealIdentity INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    RandomCol NVARCHAR(100),
    FakeIdentity INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence
);
```

**UPDATE - MySQL Way**

I just noticed that your question is taged for MySQL. Above answer is for MS SQL. Here's how you'd do the same in MySQL.

[How do I create a sequence in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578313/how-do-i-create-a-sequence-in-mysql)

[MySQL equivalent of Oracle's SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046971/mysql-equivalent-of-oracles-sequence-nextval)