# How to add multiple primary keys in a single table

Tags: mysql

I tried to create a table as following in phpmyadmin. But it gives this error:

> "#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

```
create table itemList (
    uid varchar(15),
    item_Id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_Name varchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY key (uid, item_Id)
);
```

Someone please help me.

Comment: you con not do that in mysql. How ever you can have composite key

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an application that helps you manage MySQL and MariaDB databases; it's not a database itself. You'll probably get better or more specific help if you instead tag the database platform you're using.

Comment: You need an additional index on `(item_id)`. this because that column is defined with the `auto_increment` property. Unrelated to the primary key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; autoincrement vs another key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114535/mysql-1075-incorrect-table-definition-autoincrement-vs-another-key)