# Way to get an emulated auto increment value returned from a MySQL INSERT/trigger in Java in one statement?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL table that has a two column primary key, the latter of which was auto increment when it used to be MyISAM.  When I switched it to InnoDB, I had to convert the auto_increment column to a normal int that updated itself to max()+1 with a before insert trigger.  No problems so far..

The Java PreparedStatement that does the insert needs to know the last_insert_id of the row that was just inserted, and without the RETURNING function of Oracle/etc. I'm not sure how best to retrieve that value.  Is there a way to get that emulated auto increment value without wrapping all of my insert functions into a stored function or requiring a second query?

Just for reference, something along the lines of (just writing this out, so might not be perfect, but it should get the idea across):

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id1 int NOT NULL, 
  id2 int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER t_auto_increment BEFORE INSERT ON t
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.id2 = (SELECT MAX(id2)+1 FROM t WHERE id1=NEW.id1);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I know with other DB engines I can just tell it to return id2 with the insert query, which I assume would solve my problem, but MySQL doesn't seem to support this.  I'd rather not make what would be a number of stored functions to wrap every insert, so the best I thought of was setting a variable and looking for it afterwards.. though I'd much prefer something that doesn't require a second query to the server, of course, despite said query would be light.

Comment: Using JDBC?  See [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc).

Comment: why did you convert it? InnoDB also supports auto increment columns, you should not be doing this.

Comment: Because it's the trigger generating the key and not the actual DB, it doesn't consider it a generated key, like it would with an actual (and not emulated) auto increment.

Comment: InnoDB does not support this table if id2 is the auto incrementing column, as it is a secondary column in a composite index.  MyISAM does. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment

Comment: InnoDB does support this. First create ID1 and make it primary key. Then, add ID2 column and make it a unique key and auto_increment. Then, add ID2 column to the primary key. Or, in your case, just add a unique index on ID2, then make it auto_increment.

Comment: Correction: the index on ID2 doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: Gasp!  This would have saved me a lot of headaches (and still will, moving forward).  So the restriction on InnoDB is merely that there be _a_ key with the auto_increment column and only the auto_increment column, and it can then be part of a composite primary index or whatever other additional indexes its heart might desire?