# MySQL auto increment based on field?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create auto-increment based on a specific field? For example i have `UserId` and `Status` fields, so for each row with same `UserId` i need to auto-increment **its** `Status`, not global.

Comment: This should be what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment

Comment: @dognose it depends on engine, so works not in all situations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is three thing that come to mind when I read your question. One was an auto incrementing field which acts as your ID number. Updating a table with data that has no unique ID number. Searching for fields with the same `Userid` to `Status`
Mt First example is of a creating a table and your `AUTO_INCREMENT`ing number ID:

```
CREATE TABLE tableNameHere
(
UniqueID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
StatusOrYourColumn int(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (UniqueUD)
)
```

[More on auto incrementation.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

You may have already built your table and now want to 'add' additional and or modify your fields using `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE tableNameHere StatusOrYourColumn INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

But be careful, you don't want to overwrite your settings that you have already set.

Another Thing that came to my mind when reading was where you said Status and Userid where the same. You can find these using the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE tableName.Userid = anotherTableOrTableName.Status
```

Using these queries you can update, remake, alter and query your database table.

Comment: you might not understand me - as from yours example for each `FirstName` i need to auto-incriment `StatusOrYourColumn`. So when i adding `Name1` `StatusOrYourColumn` becomes 1, when i adding second time `FirstName` in current row `StatusOrYourColumn` becomes 2.

Comment: Where I used `Uniqueid`replace with `Status`. Then when using `INSERT` give the field a `NULL` value so that the auto incremation happens. If you want to do it manually use this `SET Status=Status+1`