# Composite Primary Key and Auto_Increment

Tags: mysql, key, composite

I'm trying to do the composite key with one of them auto incrementing, but when I try to enter a new row it just continue the sequential.

Here's the example of what happens:

```
Item_1 | Item_2
1     |   1    
1     |   2
2     |   3
2     |   4
2     |   5
```

Here's the example of what I want:

```
Item_1 | Item_2
1     |   1    
1     |   2
2     |   1
2     |   2
2     |   3
```

I create the table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `cod_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_user_emp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod_user`,`cod_user_emp`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`),
  KEY `cod_user` (`cod_user`)
  );
```

#### Edit

I resolved the problem doing a server sided php validation.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE cod_user_emp=\"$emp\" ORDER BY cod_user DESC LIMIT 1");
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
   $cod2 = $row['cod_user']+1;
}
```

Comment: so, there is any way to that work without auto_increment?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that `AUTO_INCREMENT` column,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` 
(
  `cod_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cod_user_emp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod_user`,`cod_user_emp`) -- <<== this is enough
);
```

And can create a `Stored Procedure` that increments `Item_2` for every `Item_1`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRecord(IN ItemA INT)
BEGIN
    SET @max_id =  (
                    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Item_2), 0) + 1
                    FROM TableName
                    WHERE   Item_1 = ItemA
                    );
    INSERT INTO tableName(Item_1, Item_2)
    VALUES(ItemA, @max_id)
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and call it like this,

```
CALL InsertRecord(2);
```

Comment: I would do it with a trigger

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem I rather not to.

Comment: Why not? In my opinion you are much saver with a trigger, than you are with this procedure. Also, your insert stays the same

Comment: yep typo due to cop-paste. I'm not fun of using triggers though, you can post trigger as an answer `:D`

Comment: The trigger example is also posted in the other thread mentioned in the first comments

Comment: I'd like to see the trigger example, could anyone post it please?

Comment: @HeronVieira see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120088/defining-composite-key-with-auto-increment-in-mysql) for an example