# Making an INSERT ... SELECT statement atomic

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have two tables: one stores data and the other stores locks to indicate when a user is operating on that data. I'd like to select some number of items from the first table, such that they match several conditions and do not have a corresponding lock in the other table, and then add locks for these items to the second table. Since many users may simultaneously attempt to lock items it will be necessary for this to be done atomically.

I've written the SQL statement below to attempt to do this, but I receive the error `Deadlock found when trying to get lock;`.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, user, date)
    SELECT id, ?, NOW()
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 USING id
    WHERE locked IS NULL AND <several conditions on table1>
    ORDER BY date 'DESC'
    LIMIT 15;
```

Is there any way to make this an atomic operation without locking the tables? Currently I'm using a transaction and reattempting if it's unsuccessful, but I'm interested in whether this is avoidable. I'm using MySQL version 5.0.95 with InnoDB.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Having given this some further thought I've realised that whilst locking table1 is unacceptable, I can lock table2. Since I can't actually lock the table in the statement (since I have to lock all tables if I choose to lock one of them) I can instead use GET_LOCK to create a mutex preventing multiple processes calling this code simultaneously. I've not yet had a chance to test this approach, but it feels like it might be a more lightweight solution than transactions.

Comment: Not related to your question, but if locked is a field in table2, you have to move the filter on it from the where clause to the join clause.  Otherwise you effectively have an inner join.

Comment: I definitely need to read more about how joins work since I don't know about different types of joins. I assume that your suggestion would improve performance if the majority of items in the first table have a corresponding lock? Since table2 is usually empty, does it provide any other benefits?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is what the transactions are all about. They organize a bunch of statements in **one atomic** operation which either succeeds or fails as a whole.

[Here](https://blog.couchbase.com/optimistic-or-pessimistic-locking-which-one-should-you-pick) you could find some explanation for **optimistic** and **pesimistic** lock which perhaps you could find useful. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) you could find some details about the locking mechanism used in InnoDB (pesimistic locking). [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28879/how-to-correctly-implement-optimistic-locking-in-mysql) you could find guidelines on how to implement the optimistic locking in mysql.