# MySql Can i use a foreign key as PART of my primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I something like this valid?

These are the columns in my ACCOUNTS table:

```
user_id (Primary Key)
user_name
user_pass
user_email
user_date
```

Accounts are allowed to have multiple characters. Heres how i want to write that table:
CHARACTERS table:

```
character_ID
user_ID (foreign key)
character_name
...(random columns)
```

Can i make my PRIMARY KEY (character_ID, user_ID)? 
Or is there a better way to distinguish this?

EDIT: here is how i would create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE characters(
    -> char_id INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> char_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -> user_id INT(8) 
    -> PRIMARY KEY(char_id, user_id),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    -> )
    -> ;
```

Comment: show create table for `characters`.

Comment: Yes you can, then it becomes a composite key.

Comment: @Ravinder I havnt done it yet but i edited my OP to add how i think i would do it.

Comment: Yes, that would work as you have it.  I usually like to keep the primary key at the front for readability though.  For example, have the order: char_id, user_id, char_name that way it is easier to distinguish the primary key.

Comment: @Devon okay thanks :) My next question would be, how do i create the table to have char_id increment for each user_id. IE: user 1 has three characters. User 1's character ids are 1, 2 and 3. User 2 has 2 characters. User 2's character ids are 1, and 2. The primary keys would still be different.

Comment: If you want to do that, you have to program the ID generation yourself, it can't be done with `auto_increment`. Why do you need to do that? Why not just use unique sequential IDs for everyone, and use `auto_increment`?

Comment: Here is a link to a discussion on something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120088/defining-composite-key-with-auto-increment-in-mysql.  In short, you can't with the table structure, you would need to setup a procedure, calculate it in the INSERT statement, or generate it in the logic of your application (PHP, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make both (char_id, user_id) as primary key in characters table and 
then it becomes a composite key but `foreign key` allowed to have duplicates, because of which
they may not be best to use as a Primary Key.

So generally it's recommended and best practice to use a field that can uniquely
determine all other fields in a record and designate that as `primary key`.

It can be a `synthetic` one like (`auto_increment` in MySQL, `IDENTITY` in SQL Server).
or it can be normal/general like "Social Security Number" etc.

So, in your case if `char_id` can alone uniquely determine all other fields then I would make 
it as PK `char_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key`

Comment: Right, my example's foreign key is a primary key in a different table. So no dupes :P

Comment: @user3521471, these are general guidelines.