# php-How to get date wise unique transaction number?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, unique-transaction-identifier

I was thinking of formatting it like this

TYYYYMMDDNNNN (2 character + 12 digits)

**Where**

T is character (TR or SL)
YYYY is year (2018)
MM is month (03)
DD is day (30)
N is sequential number (0001, 0002, 0003 etc.)

I need auto increment N after getting last data from mysql database.

**Such as**

20180330-0001, 20180330-0002, 20180330-0003.

20180331-0001, 20180331-0002.

20180401-0001, 20180401-0002, 20180401-0003 etc.

Comment: You want to build a composite primary key? What is your db engine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120088/defining-composite-key-with-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: Twitter snowflakes would be an option too, as unique ID.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to combine two pieces of information into a single column. In this case, use a column with the date, and another that increments with each access. You can create an index on the two columns and you're good to go.