# Use UNIQUE in AUTO_INCREMENT column to create an improved PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql

Taking into account that in MySQL the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column must be part of the `PRIMARY KEY`, I would like to ask if makes sense using `UNIQUE` key in that `AUTO_INCREMENT` column to be able to create a composite `PRIMARY KEY` without defining it as the **first** PK index.

I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
a  INT NOT NULL,
b  INT NOT NULL,
c  INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id, a, b));
```

My **purpose** is to search by `(a)` or `(a, b)` and then sort it according to `id`. I would like to create a `PRIMARY KEY` as `(a, b, id)` but it is not allowed by definition. Besides, as documentation states, a `PRIMARY KEY` composed of `(x, y, z)` will take advantage of `PRIMARY KEY` only if you search by `(x)`, `(x, y)` or `(x, y, z)`, but not if you search by `(y)` or `(y , z)` (or anything else). I verified it. Indeed, with the above `PRIMARY KEY (id, a, b)` definition, any query searching for `a` does not use any `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
DESCRIBE SELECT `a`, `b` FROM `test` WHERE `a` = 0;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test  | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 12      | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

I decided to *cheat* a bit and redefined `id` as `UNIQUE KEY` (so that it is still regarded as a `KEY`) and then recreated a `PRIMARY KEY` as `(a, b, id)`. This works:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD UNIQUE KEY (`id`), ADD PRIMARY KEY (`a`, `b`, `id`)
```

Now, searching by `a` uses `PRIMARY KEY`!

```
DESCRIBE SELECT `a`, `b` FROM `test` WHERE `a` = 0;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

That changes this original `PRIMARY KEY (id, a, b)` with `id` in the first position to another scheme with `a` in the first position:

```
# before
SHOW KEYS FROM `test`;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | a           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | b           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

# after
SHOW KEYS FROM `test`;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | a           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | b           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          0 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Does this have any performance penalties or any disadvantages I did not see? This solutions looks to me simpler than triggering stored procedures to increment the index (like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637080/composite-primary-key-and-auto-increment)).

Thank you in advance

Comment: *My purpose is to search by (a) or (a, b) and then sort it according to id.* Make primary key = `(id)` and add (unique) indices by `(a, id)` and `(a, b, id)`.

Comment: That also looks like a good solution. Why `id` must be alone a `PRIMARY KEY`? I thought secondary indices are arranged after `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: *Why id must be alone a PRIMARY KEY?* 1) This matches the rule that AI must be a part of PK. 2) This decreases the actual size of another indices which always includes PK as hidden index component if it is not included explicitly. PS. In InnoDB primary key is clustered always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can achieve your goals by having id as the sole primary key and indexes on (a,b) and (a) - recent versions of mysql will implicitly add the primary key to the end of all other indexes.  To avoid a separate sort step, you may need to hint your a= query to use the a index instead of the a,b index.  If id alone is unique, there's no reason to have a longer primary key.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the query with that structure and uses those keys.

Comment: One more thing: how could I partition that table according to `a`? It must be part of `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Partitions are only very rarely a good idea.  I suppose you'd just make the primary key (a,id) then, plus a separate (a,b) index

Comment: I mentioned partitioning because that table actually contains 180 million registers. Table has very few columns and the different values of `a` are less than 10k, so I believe that partitioning could speed up things. Thanks!

Comment: if your queries always have a=, that could well be true