# MySql Composite PK with autoincrement

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I'm a beginner and i don't know too many things about databases, mainly I've been using DbSchema to create a database and i would like to know if there is any way i can create a composite PK with auto increment.

For example i have a table:

> Person
>   ------ ID  int PK_Auto increment NAME varchar age int

i would like to know if i can add as a composite PK ID with auto increment and age.

I'm using MySql 5.1

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql two column primary key with auto-increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

CREATE TABLE_NAME (
    t1ID INT,
    t2ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (t1ID, t2ID)
)