# Creating second PK as AI in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

I am trying to create a simple database with two tables:

- Group
- Participants

as in the attached screen shot:

[image]

Well what I would like to has is the id of a participat to be an auto increment as a second PK for the table, so I would have entries like

```
|ID    | group_id |
|  1   | 1        |
|  2   | 1        |
|  3   | 1        |
|  1   | 2        |
|  2   | 2        |
|  3   | 2        |
```

and so on...

I've followed the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5416667/1358670 and following is MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`participant` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `goup_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`goup_id`, `id`),
  INDEX `fk_participant_goup_idx` (`goup_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_participant_goup`
    FOREIGN KEY (`goup_id`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`goup` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> ERROR: Error 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an **auto_increment** field on an InnoDB table if it is not the first field of the PK

Try replacing

```
PRIMARY KEY (`goup_id`, `id`)
```

with

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

or if you like

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `goup_id`)
```

in fact for InnoDB the auto_increment column must be the first of the PK.

Comment: hum... the second or the third one does not suite my need

Comment: Still, you cannot have an auto_increment field on an InnoDB table if it is not the first field of the PK... That said, do as you like.

Comment: OKay, thanks for your time, that means I should think about some work around :)

Comment: You could switch to MyISAM and drop the FK, which would be useless then.

Comment: Yeah, but still I'm not allowed to switch to MyISAM :(

Comment: Why can't you use a simple auto increment key as in the group table?

Comment: This is not my real database, in my real project I need to keep a files tack per user, and I must let the incrementation goes sequencially per user