# MySQL: How to create a unique identifier based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, uniqueidentifier, unique-constraint, alter-table

I can't figure this out.
How would I be able to create a table in MySQL where I can organize it by two unique columns but one of the columns is only unique based on the other column
For example

> Rep | ID
>
> A --|-- 1
>
> A --|-- 2
>
> A --|-- 3
>
> B --|-- 1
>
> B --|-- 2
>
> C --|-- 1
>
> C --|-- 2
>
> C --|-- 3
>
> C --|-- 4

And so on...

To explain what I'm doing: My table will hold images. These images will all correlate to their report. But there will be many images in every report. These images need to be uniquely identified 1-9
(If there was 9 images in that report).

So as shown in my example: the ID has to auto_increment and has to be unique; based upon the report it's associated with.

Thanks for any help.

************Found the answer here***********
[mysql two column primary key with auto-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can create [**UNIQUE INDEX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) on both column.

```
ALTER TABLE `tablea` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `UniqueIndexName` (`Rep`, `Id`)
```

Comment: I tried something like that at first then it failed and I guess I had tunneled vision.. 
Thank you so much Saharsh, you just saved my night. xD

Comment: Actually.. I forgot to mention.. id needs to auto increment.