# ERROR 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, alter-table

I try to "alter Table"
I need one more AI field, not key... 
"List"

```
ID INT(11):PK Not Null AutoIn..
Name VARCHAR
UserID INT(11):FK Not Null
edit BOOL
```

and now i need one more field "sortpos" as AI. 
I try it with MySQL Workbench

```
ALTER TABLE `**mydb**`.`List` 
ADD COLUMN `sortpos` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER `edit`;
```

Can u help me?

Thx

Comment: as the error says, it must be part of the pkey. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment

Comment: but I need sortpos individually, like id too, so auto increment. 
Is there the possibility to clone id in sortpos, default as example?

Comment: some explanation is missing, why do you need two fields which have exactly the same value?

Comment: i need one more fields to sort the output, i need an unique key to switch

Comment: I don't follow, you already have a unique key, ID. What do you mean "to switch"? switch what? can you post the query?

Comment: i dont have now a query.. 
output as example:
1. First (sortpos 1)  Buttons: up/down
2. Second (sortpos 2) Buttons..
3. ...     (sortpos 3) Buttons..
if user click at "up" by 3. than  i search for sortpos < 3  order by sortpos DESC LIMIT 1. So now, i know, which data i need to switch, my sortpos from 3. with 2. sry for my (no)-englisch

Comment: I would suggest that you put this example in your question, for readability. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get better error message than this one. You already have **ID** defined as *Auto Increment* in your table. Now you are trying to add another field **sortpos** as auto increment which is not allowed. **One table can only have one auto increment which must be defined as primary key.**

Remove AUTO_INCREMENT from the alter statement and create a trigger to increment the new column.

Comment: can u help me to create some trigger: by insert copy id to sortpos

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you are confusing user interface with table data. The table only needs to have one ID, if you want you can create a query like this:

```
SELECT ID, ID AS SORTPOS, NAME FROM List
```

But you don't even need a query for that, you should do it only at user interface level.

Plus, what you show in your comment is merely the heading of a list, not the list itself.