# alternate between multiple auto-increment sequences using group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to run different auto-increment sequences based on another column?  Like the left table instead of the right...

```
item_id  |  group_id           item_id  |  group_id
____________________           ____________________
    1    |     1                   1    |     1
    2    |     1                   2    |     1
    1    |     2                   3    |     2
    1    |     3                   4    |     3
    3    |     1                   5    |     1
    2    |     3                   6    |     3
```

I suspect that this is not possible but maybe there's a way to do this?

Thank you for your kind attention.

EDIT: for a 2012 SQL Server

Comment: What type of database?

Comment: depends on the database...

Comment: If it's MySQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment/5416667#5416667

Comment: With [a modern DBMS](http://use-the-index-luke.com/de/blog/2015-02/modern-sql) this can easily be achieved using window functions.

Comment: Its not a sequence number more, it is more of computed column

Comment: Thanks, @M.Ali!  That's what I need and I can do some digging into that - I wasn't making much progress finding an answer with this line of question

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `Row_Number` with `partition by` should work

```
select Row_number() over(partition by group_id order by (select null)) item_id,
       Group_id
From   Yourtable
```

- [**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e32d2/1)

Comment: Thanks, @NoDisplayName: This does number correctly but as far as I can tell it doesn't create a static item_id?

Answer (score 0):

not needed.

Just Use below quesry.

```
SELECT item_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY group_id)
FROM table_name
```

[See: Row_Number(), Rank(),Dense_Rank()](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823497/What-is-the-Difference-between-ROW-NUMBER-RANK-and)

[Similar Example](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the direction proposed by M.Ali, I started looking at computed columns which didn't pan out either but it did get me thinking about another approach.  I ended up with the following solution: far from elegant but it works...

```
INSERT INTO tst (group_id, item_id) VALUES (8,
CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT TOP(1) item_id FROM tst WHERE group_id=8 ORDER BY item_id DESC) 
   THEN 100 
  ELSE 
  (SELECT TOP(1) item_id+1 FROM tst WHERE group_id=8 ORDER BY item_id DESC) END)
```

If this gets you thinking about a better solution, please share :)

Thank you to all who took the time to respond.