# JPA Entity class giving error with 2 @GeneratedValue fields

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have two columns which will use @GeneratedValues, but when I am putting them like this it is giving error;
" Exception Description: Class [class Testing] has two @GeneratedValues: for fields [Testing.SEQ_NO] and [Testing.ID]. Only one is allowed. "

```
@Table(name = "TABLE1")
@Entity
public class Testing{

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "LINKAGE_ID")
private int linkageId;

@Column(name = "TRANSFER_ID")
private int transferId;

@Column(name = "STATUS")
private String status;

@Column(name = "COMMENTS")
private String comments;

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ",sequenceName="SEQ", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "SEQ_NO")
private int seqNo;



**I have also created a simple sequence in Db using this:**


CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ START WITH 1
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to auto-generate both ID and SEQ_NO in same entity class.

Comment: JPA spec says that only `@Id` fields can be generated. Some JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus) allow other fields to be generated too, but to be portable only generate the "id" field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message says, Only one field with `@GeneratedValue` is allowed but you have two.
Please remove one of them.

I am afraid you can't do what you intended by simple annotations.
Check out this existing post for workaround.
[workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716620/jpa-or-hibernate-to-generate-a-non-primary-key-column-value-not-starting-from)

Not sure why you need two columns in same table, whose value need to be auto incremented.
If you really want two Unique columns, you can use your id as usual and UUID for the other column.

Comment: Hi @minjinyu, I have to auto-generate both.

Comment: @verma_neeraj I am afraid you can't do that with simple annotations in hibernate, bro. See update.

Comment: @mijinyu, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain why you need 2 columns in the same table to auto-increment so we could think some way around

Comment: @verma_neeraj glad my answer helps. BTW, friendly reminder. When you reply someone's comment, you can type "@"+ first couple of letter of the name +"tab". The name will automatically pop up so that there will be no typo in the name, cheers.

Comment: @Akshay , ID is primary which is auto generated and SEQ_NO is another field which has to be auto generated not programmatically but via DB or annotations.

Comment: @verma_neeraj..have you got it or do you still need a way around?

Comment: @Akshay,  I am trying out that DB workaround suggested by Minjin Yu.

Comment: DB workaround worked!!! Just make a trigger for that column value incrementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using columnDefinition="serial" with Postgresql it works for me.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(columnDefinition="serial")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Long seqNo;
```