# create mysql row with not really unique keys based on some other rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Database example:

```
| country | animal | size   | x_id* |
|---------+--------+--------+-------|
|  777    | 1001   | small  |   1   |
|  777    | 2002   | medium |   2   |
|  777    | 7007   | medium |   3   |
|  777    | 7007   | large  |   4   |
|  42     | 1001   | small  |   1   |
|  42     | 2002   | medium |   2   |
|  42     | 7007   | large  |   4   |
```

I need to generate the `x_id` continuously based on entries in (animal, size) and if `x_id` for the combination `x_id` exist use it again.

Currently i use the following PHP script for this action, but on a large db table it is very slow.

```
query("UPDATE myTable SET x_id = -1");

$i = $j;
$c = array();
$q = query("
    SELECT animal, size
      FROM myTable
     WHERE x_id = -1
  GROUP BY animal, size");

while($r = fetch_array($q)) {

  $hk = $r['animal'] . '-' . $r['size'];

  if( !isset( $c[$hk] ) ) $c[$hk] = $i++;

  query("
      UPDATE myTable
       SET x_id = {$c[$hk]}
     WHERE animal = '".$r['animal']."'
       AND size = '".$r['size']."'
       AND x_id = -1");

}
```

Is there a way to convert the PHP script to one or two mysql commands?

edit:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
`country` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', -- country
`animal` int(3) NOT NULL,
`size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`lang_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`x_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
KEY `country` (`country`),
KEY `x_id` (`x_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: create a single table housing animal and size. Use that in support of the table shown in question. That is a hint

Comment: @Drew i know that this is the right way, but **i can't change this db table** an the complexity is much more then this small example

Comment: I can help you but it is going to be incredibly confusing, and you say you can't change the schema. So idk. Why blow 20min on it. It would be of no use to anyone :P

Comment: i can't change the rows or split the table, but i can add indexes or something else

Comment: If you think outside the box, my solution is a tack-on table or two. You just have to apply the concept. You have the rep to dwell in my [mysql chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/mysql-stuff) if you want to hash it out. Good luck.

Comment: why you don't use auto increment for this field?

Comment: because it say duplicate entry where i need the same id of this same entry

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the auto_increment with the combination of a unique index (key) like I showed in my example a day or two ago. I showed `insert ignore` which expects it to fail on occasion or often. In the end, you are still left with your unique id (the PK auto_inc) that you use in subsequent calls

Comment: The PK (auto_inc) in combination with the unique composite key (the Enforcer of no duplicates) will render the id to use. The insert ignore says *I don't care about the error of it already being there because in the end I know it will be there.*

Comment: You also haven't shown a schema. This isn't even bounty material according to the Help Center. It doesn't matter that you say in comments here or there to people that this is not your exact example or table or that you are simplifying it for an illustration versus your real schema. The point is that you are not even in a position to Assist someone to help you.

Comment: i've added the table-schema to this question, sorry

Comment: now modify the first table block with all sample data and describe the sample data. How it should work in words too. Right now, your top visible table chunk does not mirror your schema just provided. If you want someone to write the code to solve the flow of operations, you need to describe in words the flow of operations.

Comment: Thanks to Drew, Sebas and Mihai - good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable m
    JOIN (
        SELECT animal, size, @newid := @newid + 1 AS x_id
        FROM myTable a
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @newid := 0) b
        WHERE x_id = -1
        GROUP BY animal, size
    ) t ON m.animal = t.animal AND m.size = t.size
SET m.x_id = t.x_id
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5525ba/1

The group by in the subquery is not needed. It generates useless overhead. If it's fast enough, leave it like this, otherwise we can use distinct+another subquery instead.

Comment: this command runs fine, thats exactly what i want, but it runs 30-40 minutes an my php-script runs over one hour

Comment: Affected rows: 18k (Query took 5.9308 sec) with the indexes @Mihai - thank you !!

Comment: I did not suggest anything ddl related based on your comment stating, in bold `i can't change this db table`. But I'm glad you got it sorted out regardless. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is a conceptual. Worm it into your world if useful.

### Schema

```
create table AnimalSize
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    animal varchar(100) not null,
    size varchar(100) not null,
    unique key(animal,size) -- this is critical, no dupes
);

create table CountryAnimalSize
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    country varchar(100) not null,
    animal varchar(100) not null,
    size varchar(100) not null,
    xid int not null -- USE THE id achieved thru use of AnimalSize table
);
```

### Some queries

```
-- truncate table animalsize; -- clobber and reset auto_increment back to 1
insert ignore AnimalSize(animal,size) values ('snake','small'); -- id=1
select last_insert_id(); -- 1
insert ignore AnimalSize(animal,size) values ('snake','small'); -- no real insert but creates id GAP (ie blows slot 2)
select last_insert_id(); -- 1
insert ignore AnimalSize(animal,size) values ('snake','small'); -- no real insert but creates id GAP (ie blows slot 3)
select last_insert_id(); -- 1
insert ignore AnimalSize(animal,size) values ('frog','medium'); -- id=4
select last_insert_id(); -- 4
insert ignore AnimalSize(animal,size) values ('snake','small'); -- no real insert but creates id GAP (ie blows slot 3)
select last_insert_id(); -- 4
```

Note: `insert ignore` says do it, and ignore the fact that it may die. In our case, it would fail due to unique key (which is fine). In general, do not use `insert ignore` unless you know what you are doing.

It is often thought of in connection with an `insert on duplicate key update` (IODKU) call. Or should I say *thought about*, as in, How can I solve this current predicament. But, that (IODKU) would be a stretch in this case. Yet, keep both in your toolchest for solutions.

After insert ignore fires off, you know, one way or the other, that the row is there.

Forgetting the INNODB GAP aspect, what the above suggests is that if the row already exists prior to insert ignore, that

You cannot rely on `last_insert_id()` for the `id`

So after firing off insert ignore, go and fetch the id that you know has to be there. Use that in subsequent calls against `CountryAnimalSize`

continue along this line of reasoning for your CountryAnimalSize table inserts where the row may or may not already be there.

There is no reason to formalize the solution here because, as you say, these aren't even your tables anyway in the Question.

Also, back to `INNODB GAP`. Google that. Figure out whether or not you can live with gaps created.

Most people have bigger fish to fry that keeping id's tight and gapless.

Other people (read: OCD) are so consumed by the perceived gap problem that they blow days on it.

So, these are general comments meant to help a broader audience, than to answer your question, which, as you say, isn't even your schema.

Comment: it's Christmas. Figured I'd leave you with something. Hope it isn't a lump of coal.

Comment: Merry Christmas, you get a +1 for your work, but it is not the solution for my question

Answer (score 2):

User variables are awkward but should do the trick,tested on my machine

```
CREATE TABLE t
( animal VARCHAR(20),
 size VARCHAR(20),
x_id INT);

 INSERT INTO T(animal,size) VALUES('crocodile','small'),
   ('elephant','medium'),
 ('giraffe','medium'),
 ('giraffe','large'),
 ('crocodile','small'),
 ('elephant','medium'),
 ('giraffe','large');




 UPDATE t  RIGHT JOIN
 (SELECT animal,size,
MIN(CASE WHEN @var:=CONCAT(animal,size) THEN @id ELSE @id:=@id+1  END)id
FROM t,
(SELECT  @var:=CONCAT(animal,size) FROM t)x ,
                      (SELECT @id:=0)y
                     GROUP BY animal,size)q
                     ON t.animal=q.animal AND t.size=q.size
                     SET x_id=q.id
```

Results

```
"animal"    "size"     "x_id"
"crocodile" "small"     "1"
"elephant"  "medium"    "2"
"giraffe"   "medium"    "3"
"giraffe"   "large"     "4"
"crocodile" "small"     "1"
"elephant"  "medium"    "2"
"giraffe"   "large"     "4"
```

You want these indexes added for (a lot) faster access

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtable` ADD INDEX `as_idx` (`animal`,`size`);
ALTER TABLE `yourtable` ADD INDEX `id_idx` (`x_id`);
```

Comment: its run over 40 minutes before i kill this process, thats not better than my php-script on over 18k entries, thanks for your time

Comment: @HQ5 Show the table definition in your question,this query should certainly not take more than a sec on 18 k rows `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable`

Comment: what you mean with table definition?

Comment: @HQ5 Run the query I posted in the comment, edit your question with the results of that query

Comment: thats to complex and is not the exact example here

Comment: @HQ5 I suspect you are missing indexes,so thats the problem not the query.But I can ony guess without the table definition

Comment: this script runs to long but the indexes helps very much, thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x_id` as this:

```
CONCAT(`animal`, '_', `size`) AS `x_id`
```

And then compare it with `x_id`, so that you will get something like:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+------------------+
| country | animal    | size   | x_id*            |
+---------+-----------+--------+------------------+
| africa  | crocodile | small  | crocodile_small  |
| africa  | elephant  | medium | elephant_medium  |
| africa  | giraffe   | medium | giraffe_medium   |
| africa  | giraffe   | large  | giraffe_large    |
| europe  | crocodile | small  | crocodile_small  |
| europe  | elephant  | medium | elephant_medium  |
| europe  | giraffe   | large  | giraffe_large    |
+---------+-----------+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: You can just use views or just query, you don't need to store it.

Comment: @user5717193 The it requires a relationship table. Are you ready for that?

Comment: i know a relationship table is the right way, but now it is too late. :/

Comment: i think somethink like UPDATE .. INNER JOIN .. SET ..IFNULL(b.x_id, MAX(c.x_id))  can be the solution

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are already using `MyISAM` engine type, You can just define both `country` and `x_id` field as `PRIMARY KEY` (jointly) and you can set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `x_id` field. Now `MySQL` will do the rest for you! BINGO!

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/346ae7/1) for you!

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
    `country` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', -- country
    `animal` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `lang_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `x_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (country,x_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `myTable` (`country`, `animal`, `size`) VALUES 
    (777, 1001, 'small'),
    (777, 2002, 'medium'),
    (777, 7007, 'medium'),
    (777, 7007, 'large'),
    (42, 1001, 'small'),
    (42, 2002, 'medium'),
    (42, 7007, 'large')
```

The result will be like this:

```
| country | animal | size   |lang_id | x_id  | 
|---------+--------+--------+--------+-------|
|  777    | 1001   | small  |   1    |   1   |
|  777    | 2002   | medium |   1    |   2   |
|  777    | 7007   | medium |   1    |   3   |
|  777    | 7007   | large  |   1    |   4   |
|  42     | 1001   | small  |   1    |   1   |
|  42     | 2002   | medium |   1    |   2   |
|  42     | 7007   | large  |   1    |   4   |
```

> NOTE: This will only work for `MyISAM` and `BDB` tables, for other engine types you will get error saying *"Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key!"* See this answer for more on this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5416667/5645769.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD PRIMARY KEY ( `country`, `animal` ); returns  #1062 - Duplicate entry '###' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @HQ5, Your error already told you about the problem, you have a duplicate entry for same country, which should be removed anyhow. If possible, clean up the table and start from the beginning again.

Comment: @HQ5, Well, did you actually try with `ADD PRIMARY KEY ( country, animal ); ` instead of `ADD PRIMARY KEY ( country, x_id ); ` ? Why `animal` place of `x_id`?